# React two useStates, one dependent on the other

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So i have two useStates, one for object A, which will initiate object B.
My problem is that my render picks up an empty B array, which causes a blank white screen for 1/2 a second. (If i try to remove the initialization on obj A i also get a blank white screen as both are needed.)

How do i link the 2nd state to the 1st state if any?

I'm probably doing the below wrong.

```
const initializeObjA = () =>{
    return objectA //pick up data from realmdb
}

const [objectA, setObjectA] = useState(initializeObjA());
const [objectB, setObjectB] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!objectA) return
  setObjectB(objectA.property); // i actually have some other manipulation done on this property.
},[])


console.log("objectB ", objectB) // always [] for first render
return ...
```

Comment: What if you add objectA as the second argument to useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 useEffects. 1 with empty dependency (which runs once on mount) and other with `objectA` as dependency.

In 1st useEffect(empty dependency), provide null as initial value and do the initialisation here.

In 2nd useEffect(which has dependency), make sure to return if objectA is not initialised)

```js
const [objectA, setObjectA] = useState(null);
const [objectB, setObjectB] = useState([]);

const initializeObjA = () =>{
    // return objectA //pick up data from realmdb
    setObjectA(data)
}

useEffect(() => {
    initializeObjA()
},[]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!objectA) return
  setObjectB(objectA.property); 
},[objectA])
```

Comment: all of the useEffects are done post the first render, the problem is the first render is seeing objectB as []. Usually i could just do a check in the return if objectB.length > 0 but i do need to also handle a real scenario when the length is actually 0 (to show that there is nothing and the user needs to create something)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a problem of async and loading state missing ?
And do the initialization of object A in useEffect maybe ?

```
        const initializeObjA = async () =>{
          //missing your api call here, no ? something like : const data = await fetchData();  
          return data;
        }

        const [objectA, setObjectA] = useState(null);
        const [objectB, setObjectB] = useState([]);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

        useEffect(() => {
          (async () => {
           const myObject = await initializeObjA();
           setObjectA(myObject);
           setObjectB(myObject.property);
           setLoading(false);
          })();
        },[])

        if (loading) return; //Could return a spinner, or null or whatever you want during processing
```

Comment: Sorry, as soon as the useState is null and [], my first render will pick up the [].

My render method has both a objectB.length > 0 as well as a objectB.length == 0 where both are possible. But the == 0 is always hit unless the useState pre-initializes (like in a class constructor)

Comment: Yes, but with the loading state set to true by default and the `if (loading) return;`  , your second return will not be reach until the useEffect treatment is done and so your objectB is initialized, no ? So your first render return whatever you want to render during loading, and after, it will reach your second render with your objectB.length > 0 and objectB.length == 0

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i could do was to move the 2nd state to the child component. This forced me to clean up my hooks / classes. The important part is to get it right the first time on the useState() instead of using the conditional useEffects. (So in the example, objectB will be initialized on a child component, instead of the same one at this parent objectA)

Kind of like in the old days, moving instantiation code into the constructor instead of using componentDidMount. In the same way, instantiating the state in useState(function()) is critical.

But it also means i can do one value at a time. Which is fine , it makes the code cleaner anyway.